# Laravel 4, PHP 5.3: Disabling magic_quotes_gpc

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

Tried to add `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 0` to `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]    
</IfModule>

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc 0
```

So i got 500 (Internal Server Error).

Tried to add `magic_quotes_gpc = Off` to `php5.ini` file according to Godaddy hosting support, but it didn't work at all.

Comment: What version of PHP is running? The setting was removed completely in PHP 5.4.0. http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

Comment: Do you still get 500 if you remove the `php_flag`?

Comment: Yessir, already tried

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with disabling magic_quotes_gpc, but with .htaccess in general.